# What can I do if the VPN can be connected but not loading any traffic?

Tags: vpn, pptpd

I set up a VPN with pptpd on my Linux server. For many months it works fine. But suddenly it failed.

The VPN can be successfully connected but no traffic can come in.

Is there anything I can try to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try for example a `traceroute google.com` to find out where the connection breaks. Also check `ifconfig` if your pptpd interface is assigned the correct address and in the correct subnet. Also check `netstat -arn` if you have the correct routes to the VPN endpoint.